# How to integrate payments section in android app

Tags: android

I am developing android E-book application in which I want to give first three chapters as a sample(Free) after 4th chapter user should pay the payment to learn new chapters so I don't get the idea how should I go through the payment and how could I set the permission to user that user will not see the next chapters.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the first three chapters in a separate activity, use in-app purchases for transaction and enable the activity with other chapters when the purchase is made.